# Не наследуется экземпляр как атрибут. Python

Tags: python, ооп

Не получается использовать в подклассах атрибут определенный в главном классе

```
python 
class Bag():
    items = []
    def adding(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)
class Base()
    bag = Bag()
class First(Base)
    bag.adding(1)
```

Я могу использовать Base.bag.adding(1), но возникает проблема с наложением подклассов друг на друга:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
class First(Base):
    Base.bag.adding(1)
class Second(Base):
    Base.bag.adding(2)
a = Second()
print(a.bag.items)
```

Это выводит [1,2] вместо ожидаемого [2], как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявляйте поле в конструкторе `__init__` и у наследников в их конструктора вызывайте `super().__init__()`, то, что сейчас -- это поле внутри класса и оно будет одинаково для всех объектов этого класса:

```
class Bag:
    items = []
    def adding(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

bag_1 = Bag()
bag_1.adding(1)
print(bag_1.items)  # [1]

bag_2 = Bag()
bag_2.adding(1)
print(bag_1.items)  # [1, 1]
```

Правильно так:

```
class Bag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def adding(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bag = Bag()

class First(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.bag.adding(1)

class Second(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.bag.adding(2)

a = Second()
print(a.bag.items)  # [2]
```